# Difference of use of [] or not in variable

Tags: python, pandas, variables, indexing

What is the difference of the below codes?

When I executed python codes, I got different results.

1st code is easy for me, but 2nd code is what I want.

I want to know the reason.

1. variable.columns.isnull()  eg. `boat_data.gear.isnull()`
2. variable[variable.columns.isnull()] eg. `boat_data[boat_data.gear.isnull()]`

Comment: Please use code blocks for code. Additionally, provide a minimal working example (with a tiny filled variable). In this case, it is unclear what the type is of `variable` and as such it is hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Working under the assumption that `variable`, and thus `boat_data` is a Pandas DataFrame, the difference is that option 2 uses the truth values from the `isnull()` call to make a subset of the dataframe, selecting all rows for which `gear.isnull()` is true.

Answer (score -1):

```
variable.columnname.isnull()
```

returns a series of truth values for the `columnname.isnull()` condition in each row of the dataframe.

Putting that inside brackets filters the dataframe to just the rows where the condition is true.

Comment: `.columns` is a misuse as it's an attribute when `variable` is a DataFrame.

Comment: I'm not a pandas expert, but I thought it allowed you to use either `df.columnname` or `df['columnname']`

Comment: yes, but `df.columns` is special. Like `df.shape` is. Not my downvote btw.

Comment: it's not literal, it's a placeholder for an actual column name. He gave a specific example of `gear`.

Comment: yeah I was writing for possible future readers, kind of